# How do I correctly create a parameter to access a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado

Working on a classic asp application and want to call a stored procedure. I'm having problems creating the parameters.

My code is this:

```
.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("BOM_ExtID_properties", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,0 )
```

but I'm getting this error.

> Description: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided

I tried adding a value for the size, but I got the same error.

Comment: In addition to specifying the max size, specify the string parameter value instead of zero. e.g. `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@BOM_ExtID_properties", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "your value" )`

Comment: Have you declared the constants `adVarChar` and `adParamInput`? VBScript does not have access the ADO Type Library declarations you have to define them yourself as constants. If you’re using Classic ASP though you can use `METADATA` tag in the `global.asa` file to include the type library declarations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include adovbs.inc file in a aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343827/how-to-include-adovbs-inc-file-in-a-aspx-page) *(the answer is relevant to Classic ASP)*

Comment: does not your parameter begin with `@`?

Comment: @ricardo It depends on what `CommandType` the `ADODB.Command` is using, you don’t always have to define a parameter name with the `@` prefix.

Comment: @dan you don’t have to define the value in the `CreateParameter()` method, but they have the size defined in the wrong argument position anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that I needed to include a value for the size, even though the ADO reference I read on w3schools said it was optional. Once I included a value for that, albeit arbitrary, it didn't throw an error.